# Turn a SubDataFrame into a DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a `by` which creates SubDataFrames. How do I turn these into a DataFrame, preferably without copying?

My original problem is that I cannot add a new column to a SubDataFrame:

```
# df[:End] = 1:nrow(merged_islands)
# ERROR: LoadError: Cannot assign to non-existent column: End

# insert!(df, length(df), Array(1:nrow(merged_islands)), :End)
# ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching insert!(::SubDataFrame{Array{Int64,1}}, ::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Symbol)
```

I am guessing converting it into a DataFrame is the easiest way to do it :)

Comment: Side question: do you really need to add columns inside `by`? That sounds unusual to me. You can just return a `DataFrame` with the new columns and have them combined automatically with the grouping columns in the end.

Comment: @MilanBouchet-Valat You are correct. It is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interesting question. On current master (to be tagged very soon) it is enough to write `DataFrame(sdf)` where `sdf` is a `SubDataFrame`. It will create a copy of all vectors though.

Here is a solution that will create a `DataFrame` with a `view` of all vectors contained in `SubDataFrame` (it should work both on master and on currently tagged release):

```
function sdf2df(sdf::SubDataFrame)
    p = parent(sdf)
    sel = DataFrames.rows(sdf)
    DataFrame(AbstractVector[view(p[i], sel) for i in 1:ncol(sdf)],
              names(sdf))
end
```

(I use `AbstractVector` container type as it will be faster on current master)

You will not be able to add rows to such a `DataFrame` while it holds at least one `view` column.

EDIT: as a side note (maybe this was your problem in the end). If you have `sdf` which is a `SubDataFrame` whose parent is `df` which is a `DataFrame` then if you add columns to `df` they will be immediately visible in `sdf` as `SubDataFrame` only selects rows and inherits all columns from the parent.